# How to create an inventory of a Meteor environment

Tags: meteor, meteorite, nitrous

The question is how to create an exact listing of what packages are installed in a specific Meteor environment, including release versions and full package names?

The smart files I see seem to be outdated or not listing exactly wat is installed, and under packages I can only see short package names.

I need to recreate the environment somewhere else, not the actual code files on top of that, just Meteor and all installed packages in the right version.

The meteor list command seems not to list the complete package data

How to approach this problem?

Comment: Have a look at the `.meteor/versions` file.

Comment: There is no such file in my .meteor directory.

Comment: What version of Meteor are you running?

Comment: I am running Meteor version 0.9.0.1.